# Null coalescing operator override

Tags: c#

I know it's non sense to do something like:

```
xstring.ToLower()??"xx"
```

because i called `ToLower()` gets called before checking for null.
is there a way around this, keeping the syntax nice and clean?

can i override the `??` operator for the string so that it only calls `ToLower()` when `xstring` is not `null`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Possible to override null-coalescing operator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/349062/possible-to-override-null-coalescing-operator)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you're looking for is called [Monadic Null Checking](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operators#Operators-SafeNavigationOperator(?.)). It is currently not available in C# 5, but *apparently* it will be available in C# 6.0.

From [this post](http://damieng.com/blog/2013/12/09/probable-c-6-0-features-illustrated):

### 7. Monadic null checking

Removes the need to check for nulls before accessing properties or methods. Known as the *Safe Navigation Operator* in Groovy).

**Before**

```
if (points != null) {
    var next = points.FirstOrDefault();
    if (next != null && next.X != null) return next.X;
}   
return -1;
```

**After**

```
var bestValue = points?.FirstOrDefault()?.X ?? -1;
```

in the meantime, just use

`(xstring ?? "xx").ToLower();`

as other answers suggested.

Answer (score 8):

No you cannot overload that operator.  Just put `.ToLower` outside of the coalesce:

```
(xstring ?? "xx").ToLower();
```

Comment: they don't exactly mean the same thing, what if i wanted be an * and for some reason i wanted it to be "XX"!

Comment: I didn't say they meant the same thing - but in your example they give the result you want.

Comment: i wasnt serious its a joke feel free to laugh haha

Answer (score 4):

No but there are rumors of a `?.` operator being added to the next version of C# for this purpose.  See #7 at http://damieng.com/blog/2013/12/09/probable-c-6-0-features-illustrated

Answer (score 3):

If you want to avoid ToLower()-ing the literal value "xx", you're stuck with the ?: ternary operator.

```
xstring != null ? xstring.ToLower() : "xx"
```

Or you could write an extension method, but this looks very odd to me.

```
public static string ToLowerOrDefault(this string input, this string defaultValue)
{
    return (input != null ? input.ToLower() : defaultValue);
}
```

which you could then use like this:

```
xstring.ToLowerOrDefault("xx")
```

Comment: There are no pretty solutions in the current versions of C#

Comment: C# is really beautiful when compared to [other languages out there](http://www.infoworld.com/d/application-development/java-faces-tough-climb-catch-net-224372). Still, we're raising the bar all the time...

Comment: Agreed. It's definitely my language of choice outside of C++. Java could stand to take a few things from it.

Comment: even java programmers [recognize that](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21007276/643085)

Answer (score 3):

Apply `ToLower()` method after checking for `null`:

```
(xstring ?? "xx").ToLower();
```

Answer (score 2):

according to ECMA-334 you can not override ?? operator

[Standard ECMA-334](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-334.htm)

Answer (score 2):

The only solution I would see is doing:

```
(xstring ?? "xx").ToLower();
```

However, I think it would look much nicer if you did something

```
xstring != null ? xstring.ToLower() : "xx"
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
(xstring ?? "xx").ToLower()
```

The syntax is simple and the intent is clear. On the downside, you'll be running `ToLower` on `"xx"` and you added some parentheses.