# How to overload Null-conditional operators "?."

Tags: c#

There is a simple class:

```
namespace ConsoleApp5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Test test = null;
            int? t;
            t = test?.i;  // in this place the overloaded method "operator! =" is NOT called
            if (test != null) // in this place the overloaded method "operator! =" is called
            {
                t = test.i;
            }
        }
    }
    public class Test
    {
        public int i = 5;
        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            return true;
        }
        public static bool operator ==(Test test1, Test test2)
        {
            return true;
        }
        public static bool operator !=(Test test1, Test test2)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

In this line:

```
if (test != null)
```

called

```
public static bool operator !=(Test test1, Test test2)
```

but in this line:

```
t = test?.i;
```

none of the overloaded methods are called

How to overload operator "?."

Comment: What do you think the operator `?.` is doing? And how do want to change that behavior with a different implementation?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349062/possible-to-override-null-coalescing-operator 
Long story short: null conditional operators are not overloadable.

Comment: It turns out that Null-conditional is not just syntactic sugar?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you literally trying to overload `?.`? Or are you asking why your `==` and `!=` overloads are not being used? These are two VERY different questions. See marked duplicate for the answer to the former (it has a semi-complete list of non-overloadable operators, and links to the relevant documentation)

Comment: @ Peter Duniho I need to, depending on the value of the internal variables in the class Test, the object is passed the Null-conditional test or not

Comment: Could you elaborate on why do you need this? Addendum: I suggest to edit the question.

Comment: @Theraot Suppose if the variable i is equal to 5, then I want the Test object to be defined as null in conditional statements

Comment: I understand what you want, I do not understand why. This could be a case of a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/208223)

Comment: @Theraot I made a simple Orm wrapper arround DataRow. And when the DataRow is removed from the table, I want the references to the wrapped objects around the DataRow defined as null in conditional statements.

Comment: Well, there is no way for the object to pretend to be null in all cases. Futhermore, usually a database does not have a way to call back into your code when something was removed (you could update your DataRow, but some other system connected to the same database could update it behind its back), which means you would know when you try to use it. You could have your ORM assume that if you are using its objects, you need them, and when you try to update a row that is not in the database, it inserts... or you could have it fail by throwing an exception.

Comment: The only way I can think of, that you could get closer to what you want, would be to have - for example - an `Entity` property that when you access it, it checks for the object in the database and returns null or the ORM object. Then you could write like this: `test.Entity?.something.Entity?.value`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you can't overload the [Null-conditional operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-). See the list of C# [Overloadable operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/overloadable-operators).

---

**Addendum** The ability to overload this operator has actually been proposed to the C# language team. See [Proposal: Allow null conditional (?.) and null coalescing ()?? operators to be overloaded](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/2020) and [Proposal: nullable-like types](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/147). These has not been aproved.

What follows is my understanding of the concerns regarding these and similar proposals:

Changing the semantics of these operators could have a lot of ramifications. For example, given that the operators are static, it would be possible to make it say that something that is `null` is not. Which would mean a lot of problems for a lot of code. On the flip side, you could have code that hangs too long on a reference or not long enough that would bring problems with the garbage collection.

Even if these and similar issues could be solved, it is not a change to be taken lightly. We are talking about a lot of problems for existing code, that is already deployed in production.